# fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken

Tags: github, atom-editor

For some reason, when I was in Atom, my master branch suddenly disappeared. And now, I get this error: `fatal: cannot lock ref 'HEAD': unable to resolve reference 'refs/heads/master': reference broken`

Comment: Solved the problem, my repo got corrupted.

Answer (score 1):

could you try this

```
 git remote set-head origin --auto
```

Better late than never

Answer (score 0):

Did you try? **git reset** I think it will work